# How to get debug output on eclipse console screen for cordova app

Tags: eclipse, cordova, debugging

I am using cordova plugin (THym) with eclipse Mars to make applications for android platform and I have an Android device with Android 4.3 due to which, chrome remote debugging is not working in my case.
Also I have tried android virtual device but even that didn't worked.
Only thing I am able to do is to run apk on my android device.

How can I debug the cordova app using eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Weinre is your friend for older Android Versions:

http://people.apache.org/%7Epmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

And you should use Android Studio for developing Cordova Apps. Eclipse is no more supported.

Comment: Cordova application development isn't more a user-story that's supported by default by Android Studio. Eclipse is still supported by many contributors, and Thym is a supported plugin. As Cordova abstracts the Android part, you don't need Android Studio to write Cordova code. Using Eclipse IDE is totally fine.